# HtmlAgilityPack - How To Get Last Item Value

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following html:

```
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center m-0">
   <li class="page-item mx-1 active" aria-current="page">
      <span class="page-link rounded">
      1
      <span class="sr-only">1</span>
      </span>
   </li>
   <li class="page-item mx-1"><a class="page-link rounded" href="/en/?page=2">2</a></li>
   <li class="page-item mx-1"><a class="page-link rounded" href="/en/?page=3">3</a></li>
   <li class="page-item mx-1"><a class="page-link rounded" href="/en/?page=4">4</a></li>
   <li class="page-item mx-1"><a class="page-link rounded" href="/en/?page=5">5</a></li>
   <li class="page-item mx-1"><a class="page-link rounded" href="/en/?page=2">&gt;</a></li>
   <li class="page-item mx-1"><a class="page-link rounded" href="/en/?page=20">&gt;&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried

```
var pages = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@class,'page-link rounded')][last()]");
```

but this seem to still give me the first link and not last

I would like to be able to get the value "20" as that is the last item in my list, this html is part of a bigger document, just fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use SelectSingleNode, it picks up the first node that matches the criteria. I would suggest using the `SelectNodes` and using `Last()` or `LastOrDefault()` method to get the last node of the results.

```
var pages = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@class,'page-link rounded')]").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is that wrap the expression in paranthesis `(` , `)` before using `last()`as follow:

```
var pages = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//a[contains(@class,'page-link rounded')])[last()]");
```